# Tableau - How to add minutes in timestamp and display by weekday

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following screen in my Tableau, I'd like to add the `minutes` by weekday and display a 7-days line chart.

[image]

For this example, I'm trying to get the output `Friday: 4`. For some reason, I'm not able to aggregate the two records vertically. I've tried different `calculated fields` but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Tableau considers time as a dimension, as most of the times it's not something you want to aggregate. To create a measure from it you can create a calculation like this:

```
DATEPART('minute', [Session Duration])
```

Once you have a measure, you won't have problems aggregating it with `SUM` (or whatever else aggregation you may need).